# Why can I no longer delete File storage NAS with the cancelService API?

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Starting today (or possibly a few days ago), the `SoftLayer_Billing_Item::cancelService` API has stopped working for File Storage type NAS. It still works fine for block type storage.

Here is the output I get:

```
[chrisr@ratsy ~]$ curl -k -u chrisr1:xxxxxxxx https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Billing_Item/129162879/cancelService.json
{"error":"This cancellation could not be processed please contact support.This cancellation could not be processed please contact support. You cannot cancel the selected billing items immediately. Please choose your next billing anniversary date for cancellation date.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}
```

This was working previously, but I tried using the `SoftLayer_Billing_Item::cancelServiceOnAnniversaryDate` api to see if it would work, but it didn't.

```
[chrisr@ratsy ~]$ curl -k -u chrisr1:xxxxxxxxxxxx https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Billing_Item/129162879/cancelServiceOnAnniversaryDate.json

{"error":"This type of service cannot be cancelled through this method. Please use cancelService()","code":"SoftLayer_Exception"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with this method please:

- [SoftLayer_Billing_Item::cancelItem](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Item/cancelItem)

e.g:

```
curl -X -k POST -d '{"parameters":[true, true, "No longer needed", "Cancel"]}' -u $username:$apiKey https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Billing_Item/$billingItemId/cancelItem.json
```

Replace: $username, $apiKey and $billingItemId with your own information.

Comment: Thanks Ruber.  I went to try your solution this morning, however, I wanted to make sure the original issue was still happening, and now this morning, the cancelService API works again.  I appreciate the suggestion though.  I will try it if the issue occurs again.

Comment: that's great, anytime